# What is the time complexity of random.nextInt() in Java?

Tags: java, random, time-complexity

I'm wondering what the time complexity of `random.nextInt()` is in Java.

I will attach a snippet of code down below:

```
Random rand = new Random();
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
int[] randomNums = new int[list.size()];
int i = 0;
while(i < randomNums.length) {
    int index = rand.nextInt(list.size());
    randomNums[i++] = list.get(index);
    list.remove(index);
}
return randomNums;
```

Comment: Whenever a question asks about time complexity my first thought is "time complexity as a function of what?". Usually it's obvious from the context of the question but in this case it's not.

Answer (score 3):

`Random.nextInt()` calls `Random.next(32)` which is implemented as:

```
protected int next(int bits) {
    long oldseed, nextseed;
    AtomicLong seed = this.seed;
    do {
        oldseed = seed.get();
        nextseed = (oldseed * multiplier + addend) & mask;
    } while (!seed.compareAndSet(oldseed, nextseed));
    return (int)(nextseed >>> (48 - bits));
}
```

This is a [Linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) which generates a new pseudo-random number using a single equation.

In practice the complexity here is O(1) because `compareAndSet` in the `while` condition will loop only if multiple threads are accessing the same `Random` instance. This should be avoided by design, as per the `Random` class javadoc:

> Instances of `java.util.Random` are threadsafe. However, the concurrent use of the same `java.util.Random` instance across threads may encounter contention and consequent poor performance. Consider instead using `java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom` in multithreaded designs.